# How to apply a CSS style to last visible word or row of text in div?

Tags: css

I am trying to apply a css style to last visible row of text in a div, which has overflow hidden. I tried #content:not([style*="display: none"]):last-child {color: red;}, but it is not working. Is there any css method for this?

```
    <body>
    <div id="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Harum, deleniti.lorem10Lorem ipsum dolor
        sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Harum, deleniti.lorem10Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur,
        adipisicing ellit. Harum, deleniti.lorem10lit. Harum, deleniti.lorem10it. Harum, deleniti.lorem10lit. Harum,
        deleniti.lorem10lit. Harum, deleniti.lorem10lit. Harum,
        deleniti.lorem10</div>
</body>
<style>
    #content {
        margin: auto;
        width: 50%;
        border: 1px solid lightgrey;
        height: 2.5em;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    #content:not([style*="display: none"]):last-child {        color: red;}
</style>
```

Comment: No, there is no direct method for this. `:last-child` of course does not work, because your element does not have any children to begin with. (And even if it did, hiding overflow would not make the last visible line, into the actual last child of the element.) Maybe you can somehow emulate this by absolutely placing an element above the last row of content, and then use blend-modes to make it change the color of the underlying text.

Answer (score 0):

I found this vidéo : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=82f07Xf0xgE

I think is more simple.